# вывод данных json массива второго уровня через jqery

Tags: jquery, ajax, массивы, json, post

я получаю каждые три секунды json массив 2х уровней типа. 1 уровень выводится нормально. а второй уровень не могу вывести, пишется всегда Array

```
function loadplace () {
    $.post( "php/loadplace.php",
        function(data){
            $('#playersonair').html('Собрались: ');
            for (var i = 0; i < data.onair[0].length; i++) { $('#playersonair').append(data.onair[0][i] + ', '); }
        }, "json" );
}
    setInterval(loadplace,3000);
```

в php где-то в начале задаются $namе1 и 2а потом код:

```
$result = mysql_query ("SELECT * FROM onair" ,$db);
$i=0; while ($myrow = mysql_fetch_array ($result)) {
    $user =$myrow[userid];
    $result2 = mysql_query ("SELECT name FROM users WHERE id='$user' " ,$db);
    $myrow2 = mysql_fetch_array ($result2);
    $onair[$i] = $myrow2[name]; $i++;
}

echo json_encode(array("name1"=>"$name1","name2"=>"$name2", "onair"=>"$onair"));
```

в итоге мне пишет "Собрались: А," т.е. пишет перую букву слова array
а хотелось бы "Собрались: %username%, %username%, %username%,"

Answer (score 1):

оказалось я не правильно положил второй уровень массива в json через php, надо было вместо "$onair" написать array($onair). В php файле последняя строчка должны была выглядеть вот так:

```
    $forecho = array("name1"=>"$name1","name2"=>"$name2", "onair"=>array($onair));
echo json_encode($forecho);
```